# I can't get my video to play in Titaniums Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer AP

Tags: titanium

Using the Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer API in Android 2.2 can't get the video to play in Titanium 2.1.2 using a Ti.UI.currentWindow.

```
/**
 * @author David
 */

var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
//var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({});

var contentURL = "http://assets.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/video/media.m4v";

var openButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : "Start Video",
    top : "0dp",
    height : "40dp",
    left : "10dp",
    right : "10dp"
});

openButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var activeMovie = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
        url : contentURL,
        backgroundColor : 'blue',
        movieControlMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT,
        scalingMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FILL,
        fullscreen : true,
        autoplay : true
    });

    var closeButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title : "Exit Video",
        top : "0dp",
        height : "40dp",
        left : "10dp",
        right : "10dp"
    });

    closeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        activeMovie.hide();
        activeMovie.release();
        activeMovie = null;
    });

    activeMovie.add(closeButton);
});
win.add(openButton);
```

Comment: my first suggestion would be to upgrade to a later release of appcelerator titanium. We are using video in a project and it is working fine